# Missing a back button in View Controller with a navigation controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

From my research on this forum, I have come to understand how Navigation Controllers work. Let's set a nav controller to firstView (a table view) as the root view controller. There's a button in firstView that takes me to secondView (a view controller). Naturally, there should be a back button in secondView if I connected firstView to secondView via a Push segue. But nothing's showing up in my secondView.

Here's my code in firstView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let messagesVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController        

    //Just querying, not important to my question
    roomQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            //Push the message onto the navigation controller

            //This will have a back button but the functionality of secondView breaks (for some weird reason?????)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(messagesVC, animated: true)

            //This will have no back button, but has functionalities that I had intended it to have 
            self.navigationController?.presentViewController(messagesVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

So shouldn't this create a connection between firstView and secondView, with a back button in secondView? I'm currently using presentViewController(), so all I need is a damn back button.

I've also tried creating a Navigation Bar in secondView and a bar button item, but it isn't showing up either. It'd be great to have someone help me with this.

Comment: Are you doing any of this in IB? (Interface Builder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing UI work in the background thread rather than the main thread. There are discussions too numerous to count about this on this site and elsewhere. Look for the pattern:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // update some UI
}
```

In particular

```
roomQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    [unowned self] 
    (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // Push the message onto the navigation controller
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
          self.navigationController?.pushViewController(messagesVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the real insights, start with tutorials like http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1

Comment: Can you please give a bit more insight on this? I appreciate you're trying to help, but it isn't exactly the most friendly response.

Comment: Amended. Not necessarily the only error but definitely get it fixed first